# Fullscreen application WM6 C#

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

Can anyone point me in the direction of how to create a full screen application in C# for Windows Mobile 6?

I'm trying to achieve a similar display to applications such as Tom Tom where all the OS elements such as the Start/Task bar are hidden and my application completely fills the screen.

I'm using VS 2008 with .Net 3.5

Thanks in advance!

OneSHOT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if it's any different in WM6, but in WM2003 I was able to "hide" the taskbar etc by simply setting WindowState to Maximized on all the forms in my application.

Comment: Spot on, thanks!

One thing i have noticed is the input button bar at the bottom is still displayed, any ideas on how to remove that?

Thanks again

Comment: Not entirely sure, but I think the button bar you're referring to is the MainMenu or Toolbar on the form. If you remove mainMenu1 from the form then it should disappear.

Answer (score 1):

Like what Matt Hamilton said, but form personal experience sometimes on ( This was WM5 and .NET 2 ) you may need to set the `this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;` again. For me it sometimes got overriden so the taskbar could show when either i multitasked on the device, or when i started to listen to a COM port.