# Running .NET Form fullscreen

Tags: .net, forms, fullscreen

I'd like my application to be run as "fullscreen" much like a powerpoint presentation is ran. The title bar is gone and the menu bar is also gone.

I dont think it should be too complicated but I just can't find how to do it

Comment: This should help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600735/fullscreen-application-wm6-c

Comment: I think he meant in the full framework!

Comment: This question was previously asked. Please search.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to do it right, including hiding the task bar, here's an article which shows a working approach:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/FullScreenDotNetApp.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you take account of multi-monitor scenario. This code will make your form full-screen on the active monitor (where mouse cursor is).

```
this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
this.Bounds = Screen.FromPoint(MousePosition).Bounds;
```

Answer (score 2):

[Here is a great example](http://www.vesic.org/english/blog/winforms/full-screen-maximize/) showing how to do this.

It requires a couple of P/Invoke calls.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (VB.NET syntax):

```
Me.MaximizeBox = False
Me.MinimizeBox = False
Me.TopMost = False
Me.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
Me.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Maximized
```

Comment: This seems like the easy approach, but it doesn't cover the task bar.

Comment: Agreed - And there is a nice solution in the article you provided.