# How to make application display in full screen mode, covering the Start menu?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-ce, smart-device

I'm developing an application for Honeywell Dolphin 6100, a mobile computer with a barcode scanner that uses Windows CE 5.0 like OS.

The problem is that I can not put the application into full screen (the start menu below the screen insist to be appeared), I tried many codes like below but unfortunately with no success:

**Solution 1**:

```
int w = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
int h = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;
this.Location = new Point(0, 0);
this.Size = new Size(w, h);
```

**Solution 2**:

```
this.TopMost = true;
this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Weird that solution 2 didn't work for you. It works fine on the desktop versions of Windows, which are the only ones I have available for testing. Related reading: [How do I cover the taskbar with a fullscreen window?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/05/05/414910.aspx), [Making Winforms Fullscreen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649877/making-winforms-fullscreen), [Run in full screen with no start menu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14554186/run-in-full-screen-with-no-start-menu)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows Mobile application in full-screen mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287173/windows-mobile-application-in-full-screen-mode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can autohide the taskbar by going `Start->Settings->Taskbar and Start Menu...` and deselect `Always on top` and select `Auto hide`.

If that isn't an option there is a **dangerous** way to prevent `explorer.exe` from loading during the boot process. For that to work `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\init]` mustn't be write protected. To prevent `explorer.exe` from loading you modify the following registry key

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\init]
Launch50="explorer.exe"
```

to for example `no_explorer.exe`. The `50` in `Launch50` will vary depending on the device.

If you mess up here you will need telnet access to your device so you can boot up `explorer.exe` manually or a way to factory reset the device. It's recommended that you have a way to factory reset the device before trying this out. It's important to note that your application must be started from an OEM launcher or by adding your own application to the device's boot process. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms901773.aspx for information on how to do it.

**Edit:** If you go the route of adding the application to the boot process you need to signal the system that the application has started. You could make a simple bootstrapper in C++ to accomplish this.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

void StartMyAppFunction();


int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                   HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                   LPTSTR    lpCmdLine,
                   int       nCmdShow)
{
    StartMyAppFunction( );
    // Since this is application is launched 
    // through the registry HKLM\Init we need 
    // to call SignalStarted passing in 
    // the command line parameter
    SignalStarted(_wtol(lpCmdLine));
    return 0;
}

void StartMyAppFunction() ...
```

Comment: Really thank you for you answer but do you have any good tutoriel to show me the steps how to o Auto Run an application after bootup  !!!! I will be really gartefull  :)

Comment: Do you mean the `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\init]` method?

Comment: Actually I want to autorun my application on the device after a reboot and I don't know where, how and what to start with, can you guide me ?  I will be really thankfull  ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Use some technique for `auto-hiding` the `task bar` (Which option is already present in `control panel` of WinCE. You can refer that).

Task bar auto-hide = Full-screen Application.. :)

Comment: thank you for your answer, but How can I proceed to refer the controlPanel ?

Comment: @user2072762 : You can get the source codes of `control panel apps/items` in this path: `\WINCE700\public\wceshellfe\oak\ctlpnl\cplmain`